# React-hook-formのRegisterを使った場合の値の受け渡しについて

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-jsx

ReactとNext.jsでWEBアプリを作っています。
メインのコンポーネントであるAppと、textarea専用のTextInputコンポーネントがあり、App内でTextInputコンポーネントを呼び出しています。

コンポーネントは分割した状態でないといけないのですが、できればregisterをつかった状態で、Appで入力された値をTextInputコンポーネントに渡す方法はないでしょうか。
別コンポーネントにうまく渡す方法が検索しても見つからず詰まっているので、教えて欲しいです。

#### コード(関係のない部分は省略)

App

```
const App =(prop) => {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm<vType> ({ defaultValues: items })}

  return(
    <TextInput register={register('testinput')}>
  )
}
```

TextInput

```
const TextInput =(prop) => {

 //ここでtextRef.current.style.heightにフォームの高さを入れたいが、Registerから入力された値を受け取る方法がわからない

  return(
    <textarea ref={textRef} {…props.register}>
  )
}
```